# Best way to sync files?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, file-sharing, files

What is the fastest, most secure way to sync files between remote networks?

My goal is to replace the local "My Documents" folder on our users' laptops with a synchronized "My Documents" folder that is actually the remote server's shared folder.

I could easily accomplish this with Dropbox, however the lack of encryption and a peer-to-peer architecture makes that solution less attractive.

What about a Windows VPN? Any free peer-to-peer applications or Windows built-in solutions?

Answer (score 5):

Using Windows' built-in offline files support along with a VPN is more or less the standard way of doing this I've seen.

Comment: "Folder Redirection", "Offline Files", and "DirectAccess" will work together to give you a reasonable user experience. Trying to cobble something together with third-party software probably isn't worth your time for the results you'll end up getting.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout wuala - secure alternative to dropbox http://www.wuala.com/